# How to Save / Restore nested fragments in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The layout file of my main activity contains a  in wich I'm loading
fragments dinamically using NavigationDrawer.
To achive this I use a FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new FragmentA();
    case 1:
        return new FragmentB();
    case 2:
        return new FragmentC();
    }

    return null;
}
```

In FragmentA there is a ViewPager + another FragmentPagerAdapter, so you can swipe
between three other fragments. (Frament1, Fragment2, Fragment3).
It works like this:

(I can't insert the image due to the lack of reputation...)

```
http://62.165.232.86:1991/images/fragments.png
```

When I swap between Frament1, Fragment2 and Fragment3, it works fine.
(I set the ViewPager's offScreenPageLimit high enough.)

The problem occures when I navigate to FragmentB or FragmentC and then FragmentA gets destroyed and I dont know how to save its instance and recover it, becaues I dont have
reference to Fragment1.

EDIT 1:
I swap between FragmentA and FragmentB like this:

```
    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tx.replace(R.id.main, mAdapter.getItem(0));
    tx.commit();
```

Im a bit confused. I should save the instances of Fragment1, 2, 3 and Fragment A,
and recover them all when I navigate back to Fragment A but I don't know how because I dont have reference to the child fragments.

Can you help me?

Thanks for your answers,
Daneel Olivaw

Comment: How you switches between A and B. `FragmentTransaction.replace()`?

Comment: Yes, I switch like that. (I also edited the question.)

Comment: try `FragmentTransaction.add()` instead

Comment: I have tried it, but it places the new Fragment on top of the others,
and the previous fragments can be seen under the current one.
It is caothic.

Answer (score 0):

Idea (I not sure at 100%):

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourtag");
if (fragment==null) {
   fragment = mAdapter.getItem(0)   
}  
FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.add(R.id.main, fragment, "yourtag");
tx.commit();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I use tx.add then the new fragments are placed on top of the fragment that alrady exists, and both fragments can be seen. Another problem is when I navigate back to FragmentA an exception occures because the fragment is already added.

Comment: If I use tx.replace instead of tx.add then the previous fragment is removed before a new gets added, but in this case the removed fragment gets destroyed and findFragmentByTag doesn't find it later.